# Clear Edittext onclick issues

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm kind of new to android programming and I've been searching for an answer to this for hours. I'm trying to get an `EditText` cleared when someone clicks on it, but for some reason eclipse isn't recognizing the `onClickListener`.
What did I miss?

```
    public class PillbugsStart extends Activity {

        private EditText text;
    private TextView f;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pillbugsstart);

        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        editText.setText("");
        f = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grah);

            ImageButton b = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.testbutton2);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View argo) {

            Intent j = new Intent(PillbugsStart.this, Startpage.class);
            PillbugsStart.this.startActivity(j);            
            }
        });
      } 
      public void myClickHandler(View view) {

                switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.FBLUB:

            RadioButton pounds = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.lbs);
            RadioButton kilograms = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.kilograms);
            if (text.getText().length() == 0)
                        {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
            if (pounds.isChecked()) 
                        {
                f.setText(String.valueOf(convertFromPounds(inputValue)));
                pounds.setChecked(true);
            }
                        else 
                        {
                    f.setText(String.valueOf(convertFromKilograms(inputValue)));
            }
            break;
        }

    }   
    private float convertFromPounds(float pounds) 
        {
        return ((pounds * 454) * 1/2);
    }
    private float convertFromKilograms(float kilograms) 
        {
        return ((kilograms * 1000) * 1/2);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You are not implement the onClickListner in your Activity That's why it is not recognising this Listner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing the Text on Click event on `EditText` is not a good UserExperience approach.

and Even if you succeed to put `onClick` listener on `EditText`, you will face problem of focus and keyboard not appearing.

You can Wrap it around using a `RelativeLayout` and put `EditText` as center and Button with text as `"x"` aligned to right in `RelativeLayout` like this. Button will appear above the `EditText` and can be made looking nice with minor tweaking..

```
_________________________
|   ___________________  |
|  |_________________|X| |
|________________________|<-----RelativeLayout
```

clear the Text onClick of the `Button` "X"

Answer (score 1):

I think you had mistaken to write the name of EditText in onClick event.
and also not implemented `OnClickListener`

You have written `edittext.setText("")` while you have declare EditText name **text**..so in onClick write `text.setText("")`

**EDIT:**

Moreover,I advice you should also write condition in onClick to check which view is clicked (Though in your case you have used for only one view)

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
       int id = v.getId();
       switch(id)
       {
          case R.id.first:
          //code
          break;

          case R.id.second;
          //code
          break;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your onClick you should manipulate the View object you get as parameter:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    v.setText("");
}
```

Also, is your class implementing OnClickListener?

```
    public class PillbugsStart extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
text.setonClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void OnClick(){
          text.setText("");
      }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
public .... onCreate(){

    ...
    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    text.setText("");

        }
    });
    ImageButton b = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.testbutton2);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View argo) {

            Intent j = new Intent(PillbugsStart.this, Startpage.class);
            PillbugsStart.this.startActivity(j);            
        }
    });
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of onClickListener try using textChangeListener

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
      // TextWatcher methods
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable statusText) {
        super.afterTextChanged(statusText);
    } // afterTextChanged

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // not implemented here
        Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged");
                //Clear your text here
    } // beforeTextChanged

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // not implemented here
        Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged");
    } // onTextChanged

});
```